# Getting X display variables in current running process using c++

Tags: c++, posix, xorg, posix-api

I have couple processes and each of them is in control of three monitors. I am currently using the POSIX operating system API `gethostname()` [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html) in my program for getting the name of the current running process.

```
#include <unistd.h>
gethostname(name, sizeof name);
```

I would also want to be able to tell which X display that the process is running, such as getting the screen name, but preferably getting the [display variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16815/what-does-display-0-0-actually-mean?newreg=6b76c05ba92a4fcb97d66d92cedb3981) `DISPLAY=0:0` or `DISAPLY=0:1`. Tried to look up the POSIX API but didn't seem to find anything that will help with my problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `getenv()` function, which returns the values of environment variables. `DISPLAY` is just an environment variable.